# What is an optimal way to design directional recoil in unity 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, roguelike

Im making a 2D roguelike with guns, and I have 4 different recoil animations for when the Shoot method is called: recoilLeft, recoilUp, recoilRight, and recoilDown. I want the respective animation play based on your position to the closest enemy. I have all the other code set up for firing, finding the closest enemy, but im just trying to get the recoil to work right now.

Is this a good way of going about directional recoil? Or is there a better way? Feedback is much appreciated.

Script attached to the gun:

https://gdl.space/itiyazuwet.cs

Answer (score 1):

your approach seems to be pretty reasonable and I believe it's going to work as expected.

I have done something similar to this once and I can assure you that you are definitely on the right track!

Good job buddy!